# Gaussian curvature in a weird metric

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, curvature, gravitational-lensing, gauss-bonnet

Consider a disformal metric $\tilde{g}_{\mu\nu}=g_{\mu\nu}+h_{\mu\nu}$, with $g_{\mu\nu}$ being the Schwarzschild metric tensor perturbed by $h_{\mu\nu}$, a generic second-rank symmetric tensor. Assume that null geodesics ($ds^2 = 0$) are in the equatorial plane ($\theta = \pi/2$) (I guess we can assume this without loss of generality?). Then what I would like to do is to carry out an analysis such as the one in [Gibbons & Werner 08](https://arxiv.org/abs/0807.0854), starting from computing the Gaussian curvature of the equatorial plane in this metric. How do I do this? Do you have any tips or advice?

What I was thinking to do was to write the line element as $ds^2 = 0$ (it will contain some off-diagonal terms produced by the presence of $h_{\mu\nu}$, but it should not be a problem) and proceed in calculating the Gaussian curvature as it is done [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LxGheHA7M00). If this is the right path, how can I properly write an equation for the equatorial plane in a fashion similar to the form $x(u,v) = ...$ utilized in the examples?